# Encrypted Value In Cookie Being Encoded (ASP.NET web pages)

Tags: asp.net, cookies, encryption, razor

In ASP.NET, I am encrypting a value and storing it in a cookie.  When I get the value out, there is extra padding in the cookie value... so what exactly does storing the cookie in Request.Cookies?  Should I run Server.Decode, or is that the problem with the type of encoding I'm using (I'm using UTF-8).

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your cookie store / retrieve code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF8 provides a superset of supported charaters supported for storage in cookies, try base 64 encoding and subsequently decoding to get the correct values.

Comment: To add to this, I switched to Unicode and this then worked great for me.